# Cannot receive files over bluetooth in ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth

Ubuntu you should add device to receive from it .so how can i receive a files from another devices without add them .

Comment: try to open blyetooth on ubuntu and check if you pc is visible then send files from your device to ubuntu

Comment: See this question and answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/153652/no-receive-option-in-bluetooth-settings

Answer (score 3):

Search in Applications for "Personal File Sharing Preferences"

Select "Receive files in Downloads over Bluetooth"

Comment: a pity we cant select dest folder

Comment: I have Ubuntu 17.04 on my desktop. I enabled "receive files over bluetooth".   I can send from desktop via bluetooth to my android phone. I cannot send from android phone via bluetooth to desktop.  why?

Comment: I can't find whatever it is you're suggesting on Ubuntu 22.04.