# No receive option in Bluetooth Settings

Tags: bluetooth

Guys I am trying to send a file from my Galaxy s2 to ubuntu but its keep dropping the connection but im able to send a file from Ubuntu to Mobile .

I have seen this link [Botskool.com](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-recieve-bluetooth-files-ubuntu-1010-maverick) and its mentioned there is a Receive Files option in BT Preferences. But in my BT settings its no where to be seen.

[image]

Help

Comment: there is a setting for only receiving files from paired (set up) devices.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There isn't really any receive option. Go to `Personal File Sharing Preferences` and select `Always` under `Accept File:` option if you want to receive files from your device without pairing it, though I'd recommend pairing as if you select this option any device can send malicious/bogus files to your computer without pairing while visible.

[image: Here is a screen-shot of Personal File Sharing preferences]

Comment: this menu needs to pop up when you first start with Bluetooth

Comment: Additionally, there should be a button in the bluetooth settings dialog which can be clicked to make the personal file sharing preferences dialog box appear.  Are there bug-reports along these lines?

Comment: In case you still can't receive files even after enabling "Receive files...", check that `/usr/lib/gnome-user-share/gnome-user-share` is running.

It is started automatically upon login by `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-user-share.desktop` if file sharing is enabled, however there appears to be a bug (at least in 13.10) that prevents `gnome-user-share` from starting when enabled in preferences.

Comment: @Roman I confirm that this bug is present in my Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: I just can't understand why it is not a default option in Ubuntu  to accept files from devices that I manually set up...it really took me some time to find this answer and I installed and reinstalled dozens of times blueman and others...

Comment: finally works! but unfortunately dest folder seems hardcoded..